# Does bacula transfer data between client and storage daemon, or via director?

Tags: bacula

We have a bacula server and several storage daemons - a local one on a gigabit network and a remote one in an office that we have a slow link to.  We want to back up a remote server on a different network to the remote daemon, but we don't want it to saturate our office's link.

So the question is, if a backup runs between the remote client daemon and the remote storage daemon, does the director set up a connection between the two, or does the director pull the data from the client and then transfers to the storage daemon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Director set up a connection between the client and storage.

[image]

Comment: This looks like comes from http://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/main/main/What_is_Bacula.html